# How to setup wso2 api gateway and Can we customize working of WSO2 API gateway?

Tags: wso2

How to setup wso2 api gateway.

Is it possible to modify/customize behavior of WSO2 gateway

1. We have our own OAuth server and want to redirect each and every request to OAuth server for authorizing request.
2. Once request is authorized then gateway should redirect that to back end service/api
3. We want add some filtering logic as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with third party key manager support in WSO2 API Manager [1].

The basic idea in here is when generating a token, the token request will go to the OAuth server of yours via the key manager component of API Manager.

When an API request comes in, the gateway send the token validation request to the key manager component of the API manager. From here, you can call the OAuth server of yours to validate the token.

To accomplish your requirement you have to write your logic in Java language. Sample can be found in [2].

1. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configure-a-third-party-key-manager/#configure-a-third-party-key-manager
2. https://github.com/wso2-extensions/apim-keymanager-okta/blob/OKTA-OAuth-Client-2.0.0/docs/config.md

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do we ensure that each API call is traversing through API gateway? Is there any way to check  API gateway is running?

Comment: You can enable Gateway wire logs - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/administer/product-administration/monitoring/logging/setting-up-logging/#enable-gateway-wire-logs